# Where clause to select rows with only unique values

Tags: sql, postgresql

firstly let me describe you my problem. I need to ignore all repeated values in my select query. So for example if I have something like that:

```
| Other columns| THE COLUMN I'm working with |
| ............ |           Value 1           |
| ............ |           Value 2           |
| ............ |           Value 2           |
```

I'd like to get the result containing only the row with "Value 1"

Now because of the specifics of my task I need to validate it  with subquery.
So I've figured out something like this:

```
 NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE fpd WHERE fpd.value = fp.value HAVING count(*) > 2)
```

It works like I want, but I'm aware of it being slow. Also I've tried putting 1 instead of 2 in HAVING comprassion, but it just returns zero results. Could you explain where does the 2 value come from?

Comment: having count(*) without group by is kind of useless. but group by alone will not help in this scenario you might need something as described in https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/
sql-fiddle with test-set should enable to provide real solutions, don´t expect someone to create it for you ;-)

Comment: `Other columns` is not a discription of your problem. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by value) as cnt
      from fpd t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

Alternatively, you can use `not exists` with a primary key:

```
where not exists (select 1
                  from fpd fpd2
                  where fpd2.value = fp.value and
                        fpd2.primarykey <> fp.primarykey
                 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've already tried solution like second one, unfortunately it returns zero rows. Maybe you could suggest what could be the problem?

Comment: @Yolomiys . . . The second should work.  Perhaps you don't have a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT myColumn FROM myTable
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However using distinct would still return a row with a  Value 2. And my intention was to select rows with values that occur only once. Sorry if my description was not clear enough.  I still hope that you'll have a nice day.

Comment: No problem man I assumed this wouldn't work as your answer but in the offshoot it did it is the simplest way to solve it